# xquery - file test

Tags: xquery

My xquery script opens several files. One of the files is sometimes missing. I need to test whether the file exists before I try to open it. (something like -f in bash or perl).

Is it possible?

Comment: Good question (+1). See my answer for a short and efficient solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Use [this standard XPath 2.0 function](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-doc-available)**:

```
doc-available(yourURL)
```